# Register font system on Mac OS

Tags: macos, qt, fonts

I have a problem about install fonts on Mac OS.
I have copied new font files to font folder system. How to register for system detect that new fonts.
In Qt framework, how to implement that?
Thanks any for help.
An.

Comment: See http://superuser.com/a/120727

Comment: Hi, my app is install font mac os using Qt framework. But i don't how to do that? I was copied new font files to library folder but how to system recognize that new font

Comment: Why do you repeat information you've already provided in your question? Did you tried the answer I've posted? Qt doesn't have this functionality, so you need to use pure C++.

Comment: I want ask to you some question.

What's the environment develop?

What's library need?

Thanks.